# mysql: Cant we create triggers on system tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers, system-tables

I am trying to audit the privilege changes in mysql.user table by writing a trigger on it.

```
insert trigger: will capture who gave the new permissions and when
update trigger: will capture who changes the privileges from what[old privilege]
remove trigger: will capture who removed the privileges and what are they
```

Now, I am getting an error while writing like

```
ERROR 1465 (HY000): Triggers can not be created on system tables
```

Can we create a trigger on system tables, Is there any work around or it will be supported in higher versions[> 5.1.61] ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**No we can not**. Even if we have the best concerned privileges are `all` and `super`

[See (All) and (Super) Privileges Provided by mySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/privileges-provided.html)

After trying all type of privileges like

```
grant super on *.* to root@localhost
grant all on *.* to root@localhost
```

I have tried simplest trigger on different tables `mysql.db` and got same error

> Triggers can not be created on system tables // Please accept this
>   bitter truth

If you found anywhere that triggers can be created on system tables, simply that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Had you seen this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,207145 ?

The poster says he needed "SUPER PREVILAGES"
Do you have access to the root user for the database?