# trigger can not be created on system table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My query is correct as per my knowledge, but gives error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `invite` AFTER INSERT ON `invite_page`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Insert into userpost(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time) 

                        values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);

    Insert into urlcontent(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time)

                        values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);
END
```

the error is:

> #1465 - Triggers can not be created on system tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I'm concerned, you can't create triggers on system tables.

See [mysql: Cant we create triggers on system tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346546/mysql-cant-we-create-triggers-on-system-tables) for more information.

Comment: But I am not creating on system table? all the table are created manually by me

Comment: Well, that's not what the error is saying. Is this the only statement you're making or you're making a lot of statements?